# variables is mistake taken for a command

Tags: bash, shell

Im writing a piece of a script that takes 3 variables from a ssh inbound connection. 
A ID 
A Name
And a switch port number

All is fin until the case is handled. And to me get a strange error output.

```
./installations.sh: line 11: ID_1=c8:2a:14:25:b7:f8: command not found
./installations.sh: line 12: Name_1=Jonass-MBP: command not found
./installations.sh: line 14: installationID_2=00:1f:d0:db:b7:48: command not found
./installations.sh: line 15: installationMame_2=JonasKirkPeders: command not found
No attached system on port 
No attached system on port
```

Have to PC connected for testing purpose and I can see the correct data is being sent from remote script. 
But why does the variables in the case mistakenly handle as commands and not just variables to set?

```
echo $1 $2 $3  >> test.log
ID=$1
NAME=$2
LANPORT=$3

  if [ -z $1 ] || [ -z $2 ]; then
    echo "No attached system on port $LANPORT" 
  else
  case $LANPORT in
    1)  installationID$LANPORT=$ID
        installationName_${LANPORT}=$NAME
        ;;
    2)  installationID_$LANPORT=$ID
        installationName_${LANPORT}=$NAME
        ;;
    3)  installationID_$LANPORT=$ID
        installationName_${LANPORT}=$NAME
        ;;
    4)  installationID_$LANPORT=$ID
        installationName_${LANPORT}=$NAME
        ;;
    *)  echo "ERROR - NO such port!! ${LANPORT}" >> test.log
        ;;
esac

echo "LAN $LANPORT - $installationID_$LANPORT" >> test.log
fi
```

I have ran out of ideas

Comment: `Name_${LANPORT}` is wrong.  Similarly a few more assignment are wrong.

Comment: l-value error from C :D not exactly but bash What you can do, you can echo these in a file and source that file :) Otherwise you can not get rid of that "lvalue required".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need complex variable names here; just use `installationID="$ID"` and the like.

[Use More Quotes](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes), otherwise the `[` statements will fail:

```
[ -z "$1" ]
```

Not an error, but you can merge the `case` statements:

```
case 1|2|3|4)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<string>_$<var>=<value> is wrong syntax to create dynamic variable.
```

To create dynamic variable use `declare`. e.g.

```
declare "ID_$LANPORT=$ID"
```

I think this will help as the error mentioned is only with this variable assignment.

Comment: Great I will try that out

Answer (score 0):

Variable assignments are only recognized when the part left of the `=` is a valid variable name. Since `$` is not allowed in a variable name, the token is treated as a command. You need to eval the assignments:

```
 eval "installationID$LANPORT=$ID"
```

Comment: Well did not need to do a eval, but I saw at your variable declaration and removed the dash and underscore. Yoola, it seems to work.